# any array of dropdown

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

How do you make this work? `<select id="sel[]">`, which is an array of all the dropdown boxes.But if I change `$('#sel').change(function() {` to `$('#sel[]').change(function() {`, it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the square brackets by two back slashes `\\`.

```
$(function() {
    $('#sel\\[\\]').change(function() { ... });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zFQf3/261/)**

But ideally you should not use such conventions for naming ids.

Comment: \\ will `escape` the special characters used in jQuery selector as per jQuery docs.

Answer (score 1):

The string `sel[]` is not a valid element `id`:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

**Reference**

- [HTML spec<sup>w3</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)
- [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Better to use a simpler `id` like `selArr`, for example.

---

**An `array` of drop-down options will not automatically be created for you.** You'll have to maintain the data model yourself, like:

```
var opts = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Then add to this array as necessary, and build your drop-down out of it:

- [Populate dropdown select with array using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446069/populate-dropdown-select-with-array-using-jquery)

This approach keeps the model and view separated, a good programming practice for user interfaces.

Comment: @Will see update. The `id` attribute is simply a unique identifier, you'll have to create and maintain an array separately.