# How to implement three select boxes and handle selection with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to implement 3 select boxes on a page wherein the value selected in one box should not appear on the next select boxes. Can I have detailed explaination to this with code? A newbie in JS. Let me know if this can be done with PHP too. Thanks in advance.
Here goes the sample code.. Let me know why its not taking the JS script:

```
    <html>
    <head>
<title>check</title>
<body>


<select name="name[]" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select name="name[]" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<select name="name[]" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>

<script>
$('select').change(function() {
    var myOpt = [];
    $("select").each(function () {
        myOpt.push($(this).val());
    });
    $("select").each(function () {
        $(this).find("option").prop('hidden', false);
        var sel = $(this);
        $.each(myOpt, function(key, value) {
            if((value != "") && (value != sel.val())) {
                sel.find("option").filter('[value="' + value +'"]').prop('hidden', true);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: u mean after select first the value of next select box appears based on first selection ?

Comment: Yeah.. The next select box should not show value selected in first select box and so on.

Comment: first of all give ids to ur select box that make some difference

Comment: I tried giving id's. . Still no success @Maninderpreet. Do i need to give ID's to the option field? or the <select> tag

Answer (score 6):

Hope this answer will solve your query:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();

  $("select").not(this).each(function(index, item) {
      $(item).find("option[value='" + val + "']").remove();
  });
});
```

Or you can go through to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v0vc673n/1/) link for live demo.

Comment: I tried this from the same URL which you have provided. But I want a step by step guidance. Thanks  Do let me know where am I going wrong in the code i provided.

Comment: Do I need to download jquery lib first??

Comment: yes u need to include jQuery lib first @AnandShankar

Comment: Thanks @maninderpreet. Its working.. :) Cheers to helping the world !! :) I might come back for few more solutions on other tpoics related to the question. :)

Comment: hi.. I need to add three select boxes with same data coming from database. how to do this with while loop? Any help with code?

Comment: [Populate dropdown select with array using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446069/populate-dropdown-select-with-array-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just use multiple select box?

```
<select multiple name="name[]" class="select">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I can. but i need to put three select boxes with selected value not showing up in next and then next.

Comment: hi.. I need to add three select boxes with same data coming from database. how to do this with while loop? Any help with code?