# How to populate MultiSelect dropdown list (MVC) in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I am struggling for populate the MultiSelect Dropdown list by Twitter Bootstrap library in MVC. I am getting the List of data on items in JSON string format. And passing to `JSON.parse($('#RetailerSelectItems').val())` but list is not enable in web page. the code as below

Inside report.js

```
 function BinddetailsEvents() {
    //Populate  Retailer Dropdown
    var MAWBSelectItems = JSON.parse($('#MAWBSelectItems').val()); // MAWBSelectItems List of data
    var MAWBDropDown = $('#MAWBDropDown');

    $(MAWBDropDown).data('allselected', true);
    MultiSelectInit(MAWBDropDown);
    $(MAWBDropDown).multiselect('dataprovider', MAWBSelectItems);
}
```

Inside report.cshtml

```
{
    <div>
          <label>MAWB</label><br />
          <select id="MAWBDropDown" multiple="multiple" style="display: none" data-allselected="true"></select>
        </div>

}
```

Comment: not sure but try to remove this line `style="display: none" `

Comment: Still its not working, Now just displaying drop down box. I am able to view the list of items in Model but its not populating in list.

Comment: here is one helpful link. [Click here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/265/asp-net-mvc-dropdownlists-multiple-selection-and-enum-support)  and change the ViewBag to your model

Comment: Thanks for reply but I would like to do with above method instead by view bag.

Comment: you would have to populate the drop down list your self, the code  $(MAWBDropDown).data('allselected', true); doesn't do anything in this context. loop through the items in the MAWBSelectItems and add them options to list. this might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446069/populate-dropdown-select-with-array-using-jquery